# How to handle Social Auth Authentication in Custom User Model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I have a Application with custom user model,it contains 2 fields (email , username) as required fields. So to create a user, need to pass these 2 mandatory fields.
 I installed social_auth_django_app package, and added Google OAuth2 Login as backend authentication as well.. 
When I tried to login through Google I am getting an error stating that user can't be created without username field. 
I googled and found there is way to handle these social authentication using custom pipelines..
Can anyone help me, how to create custom pipeline and handle the above scenario for getting extra data from Google OAuth2 and assign a username field for creating a new new user..And if there are any downsides please let me know

Sample Models.py

```
   class User(AbstractBaseUser):

     email = models.EmailField(
                    verbose_name='Email Address',
                    max_length=255,
                    unique=True,
                    )
    unique_username = models.CharField(
                      verbose_name='Username',
                      max_length=30,
                      unique=True,
                     )

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['unique_username',]
```

### .......

Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
......
#Social Login
'social_django',
]

 AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
      'social_core.backends.github.GithubOAuth2',
       ...........
      'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
 )

 MIDDLEWARE = [
..........
 # Social Login
'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware', 
]

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
           ..............
            # Social Login
            'social_django.context_processors.backends', 
            'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
        ],
    },
   },
  ]

 #Google
 SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = 'App ID'
 SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'App Secret ID'
```

Comment: there is no package named **social_auth_django_app**. Please provide the correct package name (as in `pip install <package>`) and a link to the documentation of that package. Also if you found there is a way, why don't you show the link to what you found? Or what did you try?

Comment: https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html                                                  .Here you can find the documentation for above Package. Please find social_auth_app_django package in installion section.

Comment: you said social_auth_django_app which I googled and didn't find (it doesn't exist). Thanks for correcting to social_auth_app_django which is not the same.

Comment: why are you using the GithubOauth2 backend if you're authenticating with Google OAuth?

Comment: please open up a shell, do `from django.conf import settings` and then `print(settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE)`. By default the pipeline has a `get_username` so it's strange that it doesn't already do it.

Comment: Yes I it has username declared in SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE. But in my models.py file I replaced username to unique_username. May be it's because of that it showing like that.

Comment: Have you set the [`USERNAME_FIELD`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) class attribute on your user model?